# CSS and JavaScript do not toggle as expected on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

On my Ruby on Rails application, I've finally gotten around to figuring out a sidebar. Now, I'm just having issues with the background hover color. I'm not quite sure how to change this. Here's the CSS for the sidebar thus far:

```
body,html,.row-offcanvas {
  height:100%;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#sidebar {
  width: inherit;
  min-width: 220px;
  max-width: 220px;
  background-color:#fff;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
}

#main {
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}

/*
 * off Canvas sidebar
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    width:calc(100% + 220px);
  }
    
  .row-offcanvas-left
  {
    left: -220px;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 0;
  }

  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

Here's the _sidebar.html.erb partial that gets rendered into each page on my rails app:

```
  <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3></h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Section</a></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Customers', Customers_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to 'Projects', projects_path %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
```

For some reason though, unlike the demo that I obtained this code from, the background color when I hover each link in the sidebar is grey and the text turns white, making it extremely hard to read.

Not only that, but I've also tried to paste this JavaScript code into a separate file.js, and calling it after each page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

The classes doesn't get toggled as it looks like it should. So I'm having two issues:

1. I can't seem to get the hover/text color change when I highlight a link
2. I can't toggle the "class="active"" when I click on one of the links.

Both examples came from: http://www.bootply.com/mL7j0aOINa

### Edit

As requested, here's the output of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/bootstrap_custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/customers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/projects.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="6nUnsGwrHCTVOf/90d6aHJrG+m7lnv7g2MpOix06j2M=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div><!--/.navbar -->

<div class="row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
      <div id="sidebar" class="sidebar-offcanvas">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3></h3>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li><a href="/customers">Customers</a></li>
            <li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1 align="center" class="page-header"></h1>
#deleted this part for example #
</table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!--/row-offcanvas -->
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        
            $(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
        
        </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check this and let me know is it fine on hover link?? http://www.bootply.com/YP9DV8bGwi

Comment: Hey Manjunath. I've replaced my entire section with the CSS in the example, but the hover background color is still a bit grayer than the entire sidebar, and the link text color is still white. Thanks though. It looks like this changes the background color for the top bar and not the sidebar.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't change anything for me either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer to the linked code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sidebar .nav-pills a').click(function() {
    $('#sidebar .nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

For starters, there is no [data-toggle] attribute being defined, so your click handler was never called. Secondly, the way you wrote your class toggle, every single button would toggle (You'd always have either one active and the rest not, or all of them except that button active and that one not).

Comment: If I'm supposed to add this at the bottom of the page in the <script></script> tags, this didn't change anything for me. I apologize for my lack of knowledge -- not really too experienced with JS. And by "writing the class toggle", are you referring to the "active" class that's already provided with the "Section" link?

Comment: This line of your code is the click toggle:

`$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {`

Which is to say that it's looking for an element constructed like this:
`<a href="whatever.html" data-toggle="offcanvas">Link</a>`

The code you provided has no elements with 'data-toggle' in them, therefore the click event is never fired.

Comment: `$('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');`

This line is going to look for **all** elements with the class "row-offcanvas." For every one it finds, if something doesn't have the class "active," it will add it. If it has the active class, it will remove it. In the case of your buttons, let's assume the first button is already active. When that line is fired, your first button will not be active, and every other button will be active, regardless of which button you click.

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense. I've removed that first <li></li> that was set to active, so none of them are set to active by default. However, for some reason it's still not setting anything to active when I click on one of the links. Am I still missing something that was already mentioned?

Comment: Can you post a Fiddle or something with just this page? That code should work, given the output you entered above. Though I might be misunderstanding which buttons you're trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the HTML output from the erb.

Additionally, I don't see any code that this jquery selector would apply to:
$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]')

Comment: Edited my comment up top to include the output of the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is generally designed to be overridden with whatever settings you want.

```
#sidebar > div > ul > li:hover { 
    color: black; 
    background-color: gray; 
}
```

should help you out - replace black and gray with whatever colors you want.

Comment: I can see a small difference here. It's almost like only the four corners are black, but the main background color of the hovered link still remains gray.

Comment: @user3447014  background color will be gray according to this code - change gray to any other color and it should change the background color.

Comment: Yeah I've tried setting both to red, and the background color is still gray for me.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
 .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
    color: red!important;
    background-color: yellow!important;
    }
```

Please add above css and let me know is it hover problem solved or not??

javascript

```
 $('#sidebar .nav-pills a').click(function() {
        $('#sidebar .nav-pills li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
      });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to change the navbar's colors. I'm trying to change the sidebar's colors.

Comment: why are you using !important here? !important shouldn't be used without understanding what the problem is.